# CURL C API: callback was not called

Tags: c++, c, curl, callback, libcurl

The code below is a test for the **CURL** C API . The problem is that the callback function `write_callback` is never called. Why ?

```
/** compilation: g++ source.cpp -lcurl */

#include <assert.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstring>
#include <cassert>
#include <curl/curl.h>

using namespace std;

static size_t write_callback(void *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void *userp)
{
    std::cerr << "CALLBACK WAS CALLED" << endl;
    exit(-1);
    return size*nmemb;
}

static void test_curl()
{
    int any_data=1;
    CURLM* multi_handle=NULL;
    CURL* handle_curl = ::curl_easy_init();
    assert(handle_curl!=NULL);
    ::curl_easy_setopt(handle_curl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page");
    ::curl_easy_setopt(handle_curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, &any_data);
    ::curl_easy_setopt(handle_curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
    ::curl_easy_setopt(handle_curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, write_callback);
    ::curl_easy_setopt(handle_curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "libcurl-agent/1.0");

    multi_handle = ::curl_multi_init();
    assert(multi_handle!=NULL);
    ::curl_multi_add_handle(multi_handle, handle_curl);
    int still_running=0;
    /* lets start the fetch */
    while(::curl_multi_perform(multi_handle, &still_running) ==
          CURLM_CALL_MULTI_PERFORM );
    std::cerr << "End of curl_multi_perform."<< endl;
    //cleanup should go here
    ::exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}

int main(int argc,char** argv)
{
    test_curl();
    return 0;
}
```

Many thanks

Pierre

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to check the value of `still_running` and call `curl_multi_perform()` again if there are still pending operations.

Simple example:

```
int still_running=0;
/* lets start the fetch */
do {
    while(::curl_multi_perform(multi_handle, &still_running) ==
        CURLM_CALL_MULTI_PERFORM);
} while (still_running);
```

Comment: but of course you select() or similar in between as well, as otherwise (if you just copy this example) your program will busy-loop like crazy and use 100% cpu

Comment: @DanielStenberg What do you mean? I can't add this example in the test_curl function? what seems to be wrong?

Comment: your program will busy-loop like crazy means it will never halt or pause or wait when it should